# cPacket causing simulation crash in OMNet++

Tags: omnet++

I have defined 2 cPackets msg files as:

```
packet MyLinkFrame {
    int f1;
    int f2;
}
```

and

```
packet IPv4ARPTotf {
    string SourceIP;
    string DestinationIP;
}
```

Then in my simulation, one network node receives the linklayer frame `MyLinkFrame` is received which encapsulates `IPv4ARPTotf`.

Then, on the receiving network node I create a new ARP Reply packet of `IPv4ARPTotf` type as follows:

```
if(check_for_validity(static_cast<IPv4ARPTotf *>(MyLinkFrame->decapsulate())))
{ 
    if (MyLinkFrame->getFrameType() == 0) {
       tempIPARPRequest = static_cast<IPv4ARPTotf *>(MyLinkFrame->decapsulate());
       tempIPARPReply = new IPv4ARPTotf("IPv4ARPReply");
       tempIPARPReply->setSourceIP(tempIPARPRequest->getDestinationIP());
       tempIPARPReply->setDestinationIP(tempIPARPRequest->getSourceIP());
    } 
}
```

Now it is crashing for lines inside the inner `if` block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are `decapsulating` the received frame two times.

Once in the function call of `check_for_validity()` and another inside the `if` block whenever the `if` condition passes. So inside the `if` block when you try to `decapsulate()` it again then a `null` pointer is returned. Hence, when you try to access parameters `tempIPARPRequest->getDestinationIP()` of this null object you get an exception and your simulation crashes.

An easy fix would be to pass a duplicate object to your `check_for_validity()` function and optionally delete the dulicated `msg` inside that function.

Sample modification of your supplied code:

```
if(check_for_validity(static_cast<IPv4ARPTotf *>(MyLinkFrame->dup()->decapsulate())))
{ 
    if (MyLinkFrame->getFrameType() == 0) {
       tempIPARPRequest = static_cast<IPv4ARPTotf *>(MyLinkFrame->decapsulate());
       tempIPARPReply = new IPv4ARPTotf("IPv4ARPReply");
       tempIPARPReply->setSourceIP(tempIPARPRequest->getDestinationIP());
       tempIPARPReply->setDestinationIP(tempIPARPRequest->getSourceIP());
    } 
}
```